# How to reduce image portion with numpy.compress method ? (numpy+scikit-image)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-image

Hi using the sample image phantom.png I'm following some operations with numpy + skimage libraries and after some modifications the last one exercise ask for:

> Compress the size of center spots by 50% and plot the final image.

These are the steps I do before.

I read the image doing

```
img = imread(os.path.join(data_dir, 'phantom.png'))
```

Then apply following to make it black and white

```
img[np.less_equal(img[:,:,0],50)] = 0
img[np.greater_equal(img[:,:,0],51)] = 255
```

Took couple of slices of the image (the black spots) with given coordinates

```
img_slice=img.copy() 
img_slice=img_slice[100:300, 100:200]
img_slice2=img.copy() 
img_slice2=img_slice2[100:300, 200:300]
```

Now flip them

```
img_slice=np.fliplr(img_slice)
img_slice2=np.fliplr(img_slice2)
```

And put them back into an image copy

```
img2=img.copy()
img2[100:300, 200:300]=img_slice 
img2[100:300, 100:200]=img_slice2
```

And this is the resulting image before the final ("compress") excersise:

[image]

Then I'm asked to "reduce" the black spots by using the `numpy.compress` method.

The expected result after using "compress" method is the following image (screenshot) where the black spots are reduced by 50%:

But I have no clue of how to use `numpy.compress` method over the image or image slices to get that result,  not even close, all what I get is just chunks of the image that looks like cropped or stretched portions of it.

[image]

I will appreciate any help/explanation about how the `numpy.compress` method works for this matter and even if is feasible to use it for this.

Comment: I don't understand which `compress` method are you using, but have you tried slicing out the central part of the image with the two black spots only, "compressing" that and putting in back in the original image?

Comment: @Ardweaden Sorry, I was talking about the numpy compress method, it may be the case that the exercise isn't well explained or is incorrect by asking to use `numpy.compress` but not sure.

I've tried to compress only the sliced spots but I haven't been able to get the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem ok with cropping and extracting, but just stuck on the *compress* aspect. So, crop out the middle and save that as `im` and we will compress that in the next step. Fill the area you cropped from with white.

Now, compress the part you cropped out. In order to reduce by 50%, you need to take alternate rows and alternate columns, so:

```
# Generate a vector alternating between True and False the same height as "im"
a = [(i%2)==0 for i in range(im.shape[0])]

# Likewise for the width
b = [(i%2)==0 for i in range(im.shape[1])]

# Now take alternate rows with numpy.compress()
r = np.compress(a,im,0)

# And now take alternate columns with numpy.compress()
res = np.compress(b,r,1)
```

Finally put `res` back in the original image, offset by half its width and height relative to where you cut it from.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can slice off the center spots first by : 
center_spots = img2[100:300,100:300]

Then you can replace the center spots values in the original image with 255 (white)
img2[100:300,100:300] = 255

then compress center_spots by 50% along both axes and add the resultant back to img2
the compressed image shape will be (100,100), so add to img2[150:250,150:250]

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code for the output you want. Comment if you need explanation for the below code.

```
import os.path
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage import data_dir
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = imread(os.path.join(data_dir, 'phantom.png'))
img[np.less_equal(img[:,:,0],50)] = 0
img[np.greater_equal(img[:,:,0],51)] = 255

img_slice=img[100:300,100:200]
img_slice2=img[100:300,200:300]

img_slice=np.fliplr(img_slice)
img_slice2=np.fliplr(img_slice2)

img2=img.copy()
img2[100:300, 200:300]=img_slice 
img2[100:300, 100:200]=img_slice2

#extract the left and right images
img_left = img2[100:300,100:200]
img_right = img2[100:300,200:300]

#reduce the size of the images extracted using compress
#numpy.compress([list of states as True,False... or 1,0,1...], axis = (0 for column-wise and 1 for row-wise))
#In state list whatever is False or 0 that particular row should will be removed from that matrix or image
#note: len(A) -> number of rows and len(A[0]) number of columns

#reducing the  height-> axis  = 0
img_left = img_left.compress([not(i%2) for i in range(len(img_left))],axis = 0)
#reducing the  width-> axis  = 1
img_left = img_left.compress([not(i%2) for i in range(len(img_left[0]))],axis = 1)

#reducing the  height-> axis  = 0
img_right = img_right.compress([not(i%2) for i in range(len(img_right))],axis = 0)
#reducing the  width-> axis  = 1
img_right = img_right.compress([not(i%2) for i in range(len(img_right[0]))],axis = 1)

#clearing the area before pasting the left and right minimized images
img2[100:300,100:200] = 255 #255 is for whitening the pixel
img2[100:300,200:300] = 255

#paste the reduced size images back into the main picture(but notice the coordinates!)
img2[150:250,125:175] = img_left
img2[150:250,225:275] = img_right
plt.imshow(img2)
```

`numpy.compress` document [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
eyes = copy[100:300,100:300]
eyes1 = eyes
e = [(i%2 == 0) for i in range(eyes.shape[0])]
f = [(i%2 == 0) for i in range(eyes.shape[1])]
eyes1 = eyes1.compress(e,axis = 0)
eyes1 = eyes1.compress(f,axis = 1)
# plt.imshow(eyes1)
copy[100:300,100:300] = 255
copy[150:250,150:250] = eyes1
plt.imshow(copy)
```